# Selecting the last value of a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, custom-function

I have a spreadsheet with some values in column G. Some cells are empty in between, and I need to get the last value from that column into another cell.

Something like:

```
=LAST(G2:G9999)
```

except that `LAST` isn't a function.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So this solution takes a string as its parameter. It finds how many rows are in the sheet. It gets all the values in the column specified. It loops through the values from the end to the beginning until it finds a value that is not an empty string. Finally it retunrs the value.

**Script:**

```
function lastValue(column) {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + "1:" + column + lastRow).getValues();

  for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
  return values[lastRow - 1];
}
```

**Usage:**

```
=lastValue("G")
```

**EDIT:**

In response to the comment asking for the function to update automatically:

The best way I could find is to use this with the code above:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(lastValue("G"));
}
```

It would no longer be required to use the function in a cell like the **Usage** section states. Instead you are hard coding the cell you would like to update and the column you would like to track. It is possible that there is a more eloquent way to implement this (hopefully one that is not hard coded), but this is the best I could find for now.

Note that if you use the function in cell like stated earlier, it will update upon reload. Maybe there is a way to hook into `onEdit()` and force in cell functions to update. I just can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: This is a Google Spreadsheet script. You can create a new script under `Tools -> Scripts -> Script editor...`

Comment: :O that is amazing! I didn't know Google had implemented scripts. Thank you very much, it worked perfectly

Comment: any idea how to make it update automatically when I change the data in the sheet?

Comment: I edited my answer with some information that should help. Happy coding!

Comment: I've made an edit to this script so you can pass named sheets into it like lastValue("Sheet1!A") https://gist.github.com/2701061

Answer (score 168):

Similar answer to [caligari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356890), but we can tidy it up by just specifying the full column range:

```
=INDEX(G2:G, COUNT(G2:G))
```

Comment: This appears to work as long as there are no blanks in the dataset

Comment: Another good resource is the selected answer at http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/p3t3feg7Jic which shows how to get the first, last, or nth row in a `FILTER()`ed range, similar to [@Geta's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5042904/873263).

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8161172/418111 has a formula that supports blanks cells.

Comment: Or `=INDEX(G2:G10; COUNT(G2:G10))` if you're trying to put this in the same column. Just put it outside the defined range.

Comment: As @KeithSirmons mentioned. It there are blanks in your column it doesn't work, because `COUNT(G2:G)` returns 0. Instead use `COUNTA(G2:G)` that counts only the number of values in a dataset. `COUNTA` is only useful combined with `INDEX` to get the last value if there is not a single blank between your values.

Comment: Also note if your values are not numeric, you'll need `COUNTA`. `COUNT` only counts numeric values: it will return 0 when given e.g. text cells.

Comment: The comma should be a semicolon, otherwise I got formula parse error from Google Spreadsheet. `=INDEX(G2:G; COUNT(G2:G))`

Comment: Another option to extract values greater than 0   =INDEX(G2:G, COUNTIF(G2:G,">0"))

Answer (score 53):

Actually I found a simpler solution here:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=20f1741a2e663bca&hl=en

It looks like this:

```
=FILTER( A10:A100 , ROW(A10:A100) =MAX( FILTER( ArrayFormula(ROW(A10:A100)) , NOT(ISBLANK(A10:A100)))))
```

Comment: Wow this is incredibly clean. Can you explain exactly how it works?

Comment: Not really: it is right just when source range is already sorted.

Comment: Explained: `ROW` returns the row number, so `FILTER( ROW(A10:A100), NOT(ISBLANK(A10:A100) )` returns an array of all the non-blank row numbers (not their values), for example [1,2, 3, 7, 12, 14]. Then `MAX` gives us the last row number. A second `FILTER` is then applied to filter out all rows where the row number doesn't match the value from `MAX` (i.e. the value of the last non-blank row).

Comment: Both instances of ROW can be replaced by COLUMN in order to return the last value in a particular row (instead of the last value in a particular column).

Comment: What if I just wanted the row number of the last value of the column?

Comment: @Nick5a1, then you remove the extra (outter) `FILTER` since the `=MAX(...)` is the answer you are asking for.

Answer (score 45):

LAST() function is not implemented at the moment in order to select the last cell within a range. However, following your example:

```
=LAST(G2:G9999)
```

we are able to obtain last cell using the couple of functions **INDEX()** and **COUNT()** in this way:

```
=INDEX(G2:G; COUNT(G2:G))
```

There is a **[live example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3UZ9SFEipyqe2LGngiXyS59gcK4sAWzFuYi9ZhMmsw/edit#gid=5)** at the spreedsheet where I have found (and solved) the same problem (sheet `Orzamentos`, cell `I5`). Note that it works perfectly even refering to other sheets within the document.

Comment: This works great, and auto-updates as the sheet changes.  Thanks!

Comment: I like the conciseness of this suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work when the target range includes some blank cells (as mentioned in the original question above), since COUNT() doesn't count blank cells.

Comment: @JonSchneider you can use `COUNTA` in that case if you're sure there is not a single blank between the values in the column. See my comments to dohmoose's answer.

Comment: Why does `:G` denote the last element? Is this documented?

Answer (score 42):

### Summary:

```
=INDEX( FILTER( G2:G , NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))) , COUNTA(G2:G) )
```

### Details:

I've looked through and tried several answers, and here's what I've found:
The simplest solution (see [Dohmoose' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871043/)) works if there are no blanks:

```
=INDEX(G2:G; COUNT(G2:G))
```

If you have blanks, it fails.

You can handle one blank by just changing from `COUNT` to `COUNTA`  (See [user3280071's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21606162)):

```
=INDEX(G2:G; COUNTA(G2:G))
```

However, this will fail for some combinations of blanks. (`1 blank 1 blank 1` fails for me.)

The following code works (See [Nader's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22798829) and [jason's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169914/selecting-the-last-value-of-a-column/13356890#comment39886037_22798829)):

```
=INDEX( FILTER( G2:G , NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))) , ROWS( FILTER( G2:G , NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G)) ) ) )
```

but it requires thinking about whether you want to use `COLUMNS` or `ROWS` for a given range.

However, if `COLUMNS` is replaced with `COUNT` I seem to get a reliable, blank-proof implementation of `LAST`:

```
=INDEX( FILTER( G2:G , NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))) , COUNT( FILTER( G2:G , NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G)) ) ) )
```

And since `COUNTA` has the filter built in, we can simplify further using

```
=INDEX( FILTER( G2:G , NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))) , COUNTA(G2:G) )
```

This is somewhat simple, and correct. And you don't have to worry about whether to count rows or columns. And unlike script solutions, it automatically updates with changes to the spreadsheet.

And if you want to get the last value in a row, just change the data range:

```
=INDEX( FILTER( A2:2 , NOT(ISBLANK(A2:2))) , COUNTA(A2:2) )
```

Comment: Super helpful to walk through the steps and functionality+limitations of each iteration.  I needed to to get the last value in each row, some with multiple blanks.  This worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

In order to return the last value from a column of text values you need to use COUNTA, so you would need this formula:

```
=INDEX(G2:G; COUNTA(G2:G))
```

Comment: But only if there is not a single blank between your values. If there is,  `COUNTA` combined with `INDEX` won't return the last value in the column.

Answer (score 8):

try this:
`=INDIRECT("B"&arrayformula(max((B3:B<>"")*row(B3:B))))`

Suppose the column in which you are looking for the last value is B.

And yes, it works with blanks.

Answer (score 7):

This one works for me:

```
=INDEX(I:I;MAX((I:I<>"")*(ROW(I:I))))
```

Comment: A nice solution, which works in the presence of empty cells, too.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like Google Apps Script now supports ranges as function parameters. This solution accepts a range:

```
// Returns row number with the last non-blank value in a column, or the first row
//   number if all are blank.
// Example: =rowWithLastValue(a2:a, 2)
// Arguments
//   range: Spreadsheet range.
//   firstRow: Row number of first row. It would be nice to pull this out of
//     the range parameter, but the information is not available.
function rowWithLastValue(range, firstRow) {
  // range is passed as an array of values from the indicated spreadsheet cells.
  for (var i = range.length - 1;  i >= 0;  -- i) {
    if (range[i] != "")  return i + firstRow;
  }
  return firstRow;
}
```

Also see discussion in Google Apps Script help forum: [How do I force formulas to recalculate?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=3b85b82e1ef623e3&hl=en)

Answer (score 6):

I looked at the previous answers and they seem like they're working too hard.  Maybe scripting support has simply improved.  I think the function is expressed like this:

```
function lastValue(myRange) {
    lastRow = myRange.length;
    for (; myRange[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--)
    { /*nothing to do*/ }
    return myRange[lastRow - 1];
}
```

In my spreadsheet I then use:

```
= lastValue(E17:E999)
```

In the function, I get an array of values with one per referenced cell and this just iterates from the end of the array backwards until it finds a non-empty value or runs out of elements.  Sheet references should be interpreted before the data is passed to the function.  Not fancy enough to handle multi-dimensions, either.  The question did ask for the last cell in a single column, so it seems to fit. It will probably die on if you run out of data, too.

Your mileage may vary, but this works for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
function lastRow(column){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastRowRange=sheet.getRange(column+startRow);
  return lastRowRange.getValue();
}
```

no hard coding.

Answer (score 5):

This gets the last value and handles empty values:

```
=INDEX(  FILTER( H:H ; NOT(ISBLANK(H:H))) ; ROWS( FILTER( H:H ; NOT(ISBLANK(H:H)) ) ) )
```

Comment: works for columns too. I just substituted a few things. `=INDEX( FILTER( 88:88 , NOT(ISBLANK(88:88))) , columns( FILTER( 88:88 , NOT(ISBLANK(88:88)) ) ) )`

Comment: generic solution: `=INDEX( FILTER( indirect(row()&":"&row()) , NOT(ISBLANK(indirect(row()&":"&row())))) , columns( FILTER( indirect(row()&":"&row()) , NOT(ISBLANK(indirect(row()&":"&row()))) ) ) )`

Comment: To me, this is the "right" answer. Reasonably compact and easy to understand, and works with blanks.

Answer (score 5):

In a column with blanks, you can get the last value with

```
=+sort(G:G,row(G:G)*(G:G<>""),)
```

Comment: A nice solution.  I suspect @Pedro's variant (using INDEX and MAX) may be slightly more efficient than using SORT, though.

Answer (score 4):

The answer

```
$ =INDEX(G2:G; COUNT(G2:G))
```

doesn't work correctly in LibreOffice. However, with a small change, it works perfectly.

```
$ =INDEX(G2:G100000; COUNT(G2:G100000))
```

It always works only if the true range is smaller than `(G2:G10000)`

Comment: This post was tagged "Google Spreadsheet" and "Google Apps Script", nothing related to Libre Office... you're off topic

Comment: Not terribly far off topic as the question's title, _Selecting the last value of a column_, could easily be found by some poor soul using LibreOffice or Numbers. I'm a spreadsheet amateur who knows enough to be dangerous. What I can gather is that Google has made it so that if your second argument to a range is just a column, it will select the remainder of the column so people don't have to use the very large number hack you discovered.

Answer (score 3):

Is it acceptable to answer the original question with a strictly off topic answer:) 
You can write a formula in the spreadsheet to do this. Ugly perhaps? but effective in the normal operating of a spreadsheet.

```
=indirect("R"&ArrayFormula(max((G:G<>"")*row(G:G)))&"C"&7)


(G:G<>"") gives an array of true false values representing non-empty/empty cells
(G:G<>"")*row(G:G) gives an array of row numbers with zeros where cell is empty
max((G:G<>"")*row(G:G)) is the last non-empty cell in G
```

This is offered as a thought for a range of questions in the script area that could be delivered reliably with array formulas which have the advantage of often working in *similar* fashion in excel and openoffice.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getDashboardSheet(spreadsheet) {
  var sheetName = 'Name';
  return spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
}
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);  
      var dashboardSheet = getDashboardSheet(spreadsheet);
      Logger.log('see:'+dashboardSheet.getLastRow());
```

Answer (score 3):

I was playing with the code given by @tinfini, and thought people might benefit from what I think is a slightly more elegant solution (note I don't think scripts worked quite the same way when he created the original answer)...

```
//Note that this function assumes a single column of values, it will 
//not  function properly if given a multi-dimensional array (if the 
//cells that are captured are not in a single row).

function LastInRange(values) 
{
  for (index = values.length - 1; values[index] == "" && index > 0; index--) {}
  return String(values[index]);
}
```

In usage it would look like this:

```
=LastInRange(D2:D)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another way may be it will help you

`=INDEX( SORT( A5:D ; 1 ; FALSE) ; 1 )` -will return last row

More info from anab here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/How-to-Documents/if0_fGVINmI

Comment: Not really: it is right just when source range is already sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding @Jon_Schneider's comment, if the column has blank cells just use **COUNTA()**

```
=INDEX(G2:G; COUNT**A**(G2:G))
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. The difference between COUNT and COUNTA is in the distinction between numbers and text, which is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Found a slight variation that worked to eliminate blanks from the bottom of the table.
=index(G2:G,COUNTIF(G2:G,"<>"))

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one had ever given this answer before. But this should be the shortest and it even works in excel :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/(G2:G<>""),G2:G))
```

`G2:G<>""` creates a array of 1/true(1) and 1/false(0).  Since `LOOKUP` does a top down approach to find `2` and Since it'll never find 2,it comes up to the last non blank row and gives the position of that.

The other way to do this, as others might've mentioned, is:

```
=INDEX(G2:G,MAX((ISBLANK(G2:G)-1)*-ROW(G2:G))-1)
```

Finding the `MAX`imum `ROW` of the non blank row and feeding it to `INDEX`

In a zero blank interruption array,  Using `INDIRECT` `RC` notation with `COUNTBLANK`   is another option.  If V4:V6 is occupied with entries,  then,

**V18**:

```
=INDIRECT("R[-"&COUNTBLANK(V4:V17)+1&"]C",0)
```

will give the position of V6.

Answer (score 1):

to get the last value from a column you can also use `MAX` function with `IF` function

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("G"&MAX(IF(G:G<>"", ROW(G:G), )), 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through way too many of these implementations of last-row for a specific column. Many solutions work but are slow for large or multiple datasets. One of my use cases requires me to check the last row in specific columns across multiple spreadsheets. What I have found is that taking the whole column as a range and then iterating through it is too slow, and adding a few of these together makes the script sluggish.

My "hack" has been this formula:

```
=ROW(index(sheet!A2:A,max(row(sheet!A2:A)*(sheet!A2:A<>""))))-1
```

- Example: Add this to Cell A1, to find the last row in column A. Can be added anywhere, just make sure to manage the "-1" at the end depending on which row the formula is placed. You can also place this is another col, rather than the one you're trying to count, and you don't need to manage the -1. You could also count FROM a starting Row, like "C16:C" - will count values C16 onwards
- This formula is reliably giving me the last row, including blanks in the middle of the dataset
- To use this value in my GS code, I am simply reading the cell value from A1. I understand that Google is clear that spreadsheet functions like read/write are heavy (time-consuming), but this is much faster than column count last-row methods in my experience (for large datasets)
- To make this efficient, I am getting the last row in a col once, then saving it as a global variable and incrementing in my code to track which rows I should be updating. Reading the cell every-time your loop needs to make an update will be too inefficient. Read once, iterate the value, and the A1 cell formula (above) is "storing" the updated value for the next time your function runs

Please let me know if this was helpful to you! If I encounter any issues I will comment on this answer.

Comment: I think using helper cells is a great approach to save time by not re-computing expensive operations.

Comment: I'm curious about the performance of the formula itself. I wonder if using more built-in functions is more performant than arithmetic operations. For example, I wonder how this compares in terms of performance: `=MATCH(1, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(sheet!A2:A), #N/A, 0)))`

Comment: My thoughts are that `MAX` requires checking every cell, whereas `MATCH` might be able to short-circuit on the assumption that its input range is sorted (which it will be if it's only zeroes, since `#N/A` errors are not considered during a match from what I've observed). I am assuming that `ARRAYFORMULA` evaluation is done lazily and that `MATCH` does some sort of binary search scan that tests the last entry of a row/column fairly early, but I don't know if these assumptions are true.

Answer (score 1):

***Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116043/get-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-in-google-sheets)***

---

This problem can now be easily solved using the [recently released](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/01/google-sheets-powerful-functions-advanced-analysis.html) [`TOCOL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258) and [`CHOOSEROWS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13196659) functions.

```cpp
=CHOOSEROWS(TOCOL(A2:A,1),-1)
```

[image]

The `TOCOL` function with second argument set to `1` removes the blank values in the range `A2:A` and the `CHOOSEROWS` function with second argument set to `-1` returns the first value from the bottom (i.e. the last value).

The same formula can also be used to return the last non-empty value from a row:

[image]

**Note**: In order for this formula to work, the empty values in the range must be actual empty values, not empty strings `""`. If the range contains empty strings, use the following formula instead:

```cpp
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`=QUERY({G2:G9999,ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(G2:G9999))},"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null Order By Col2 desc limit 1",0)`

In the query, `Col1` refers to column `G`, and `Col2` refers to a virtual column, populated with the row numbers returned by `ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(G2:G9999))`.

I haven't evaluated the other answers, so I can't say if this is the best way, but it worked for me.

Bonus: to return the first non-empty cell:
`QUERY({G2:G9999},"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null limit 1",0)`

Refs: [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en), [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en).