# Sparkline with dynamic range based on dates in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have ascending dates in column `A` and percentages in column `B`. Here is an excerpt (last 5 rows):

```
       A                     B
 728   4/30/2018 9:24:09     36.80%
 732   4/30/2018 10:05:44    36.93%
 730   4/30/2018 10:52:41    36.99%
 731   4/30/2018 11:23:50    36.95%
 732   4/30/2018 12:42:06    36.75%
```

I want to plot a `sparkline` in cell `C1` based only on percentages in column `B` that are from the last week. *Edit: Please note that the last week should end at the last (most recent) date appearing in column `A`*.

The end result should return a range between a specific `B` cell and up to the last non-empty `B` cell, to be used in the `sparkline` formula. **How do I get this range?**

Note: I imagine it should be something along the lines of `=sparkline(x&:B)`, where `x` is the `B` cell that matches (same row) the `A` cell that has the date that's a week ealier than the date in the last populated `A` cell. But I'm not sure how to get this date, and how to write the `sparkline` formula.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=sparkline(
  indirect("B"&match(today()-7, A:A, true)):
  indirect("B"&match(today(), A:A, true))
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I have, posting screenshot now.

Comment: Great to hear that it works for you, it's customary to accept/upvote the answer :-)

Comment: The OP had specified that it's only the last 5 rows, it's easy to extrapolate how the rest of the data is expected to look like.

Comment: Thanks, works! Although I should have been more clear - when I said "the last week" I meant the last week up to the most recent date in column A (which doesn't necessarily match `today()`). To do this I replaced `today()` with `INDEX(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),ROWS(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))))` (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116043/get-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-in-google-sheets)).

Comment: @DavidSpivak That seems a quite complicated way of achieving the same as just MAX(A:A) :-)