# Exclude empty cells when using SORT() in descending order

Tags: google-sheets

**Use case**

Sort formula against other sheet but exclude empty values after last item. Empty values get sorted at top, creating a whole bunch of blank space, and then data I care about.

```
=SORT('other sheet'!A1:C36,'other sheet'!D1:D36,FALSE)
```

- A-C is the data I wish to show.
- D is the column I wish to sort on.

**Problem**

The "36" must be manually updated each time I add/remove a row to 'other sheet'.

Possible solution would be:

Get the row number of the last non-empty cell in a column in Google Sheets as [last row].

```
=SORT('other sheet'!A1:C[last row],'other sheet'!D1:D[last row],FALSE)
```

**What I tried**

Lookup("",'other sheet'!A:A)

- Result: #N/A
- No examples in Help for finding empty cells

[Get the last non-empty cell in a column in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116043/get-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-in-google-sheets)

- Returns value not address. Could find that value in row but not as efficient. Also what if value is found in more than one place?

** Example Speadsheet **
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bqiVe3pBYDJFtrO4EysSKTDq17lzY5r2b8sPV-KnTdI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Try `indirect()` or `index()` or `filter()`

Comment: Strange, I recreate it with 3 rows and the issue is gone. Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot recreate this in a new spreadsheet. I believe this may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last row, you can use the following formula.

=SORT(*INDIRECT("'other sheet'!A1:C"&**QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(ROW('other sheet'!A:A),'other sheet'!A:A="")),"select Col1")**)*,*INDIRECT("'other sheet'!D1:D"&**QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(ROW('other sheet'!A:A),'other sheet'!A:A="")),"select Col1")**)*,FALSE)

The code in bold is a formula to find the first blank cell in column A in 'other sheet'.
The code in italic return a reference range based on the bolded code.
I hope this help even though it seems to be a very long time since your question.

Edited: I just found out that query can limit rows.

=SORT(*INDIRECT("'other sheet'!A1:C"&**QUERY(FILTER(ROW('other sheet'!A:A),'other sheet'!A:A=""),"limit 1")**)*,*INDIRECT("'other sheet'!D1:D"&**QUERY(FILTER(ROW('other sheet'!A:A),'other sheet'!A:A=""),"limit 1")**)*,FALSE)

Edited: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully. If you want to remove the first blank cell when sort in descending order, you just have to simply add a QUERY function at front, without query for anything.

`=QUERY(SORT(INDIRECT("'other sheet'!A1:C"&QUERY(FILTER(ROW('other sheet'!A:A),'other sheet'!A:A=""),"limit 1")),INDIRECT("'other sheet'!D1:D"&QUERY(FILTER(ROW('other sheet'!A:A),'other sheet'!A:A=""),"limit 1")),FALSE),"")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to shuffle twice and use Query to ignore the blanks. The first sort will take away the first blank, the query will take away all the rest.
The function is as follows:
=Sort(Query(SORT(A2:B,2,true),"select * where Col2 is not NULL order by Col2 desc"),2,false)