# How to auto-increment in spreadsheets by formula?

Tags: google-sheets, auto-increment, array-formulas

I know this drag and drop in spreadsheets.

[image: sheets]

I want the first column with auto-increment. But I have thousands of record so how can I auto increment by any formula for a specific range or up to the bottom of spreadsheets.

I want formula like:

```
=A1+1
=row(A1)+1
```

Comment: If your first cell is static value, then you can use the below formula

This formula has to be place in `B2`

`="s"&MID(B1,2,LEN(B1)-1)+1` 

Select the range and control + D

Head's up : Using this formula will increase the Excel size(in-case you want this output for more rows). I would suggest to have VBA code for this process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a specific range (ex: first 100 rows)

```
=Arrayformula("S"&row(A1:A100))
```

Or, all the way to the bottom:

```
=Arrayformula("S"&row(A:A))
```

Comment: working fine but if i want to start from 101 to 2000 then

Comment: If you'd want row 101 to be the first number, you can try inr row 101 (or where ever you want) =Arrayformula("S"&row(A101:A2000)-100)

Comment: thanks. this one solve my problem =Arrayformula(row(A101:A2000))

Comment: @JPV How to set the end range to last non-empty cell? I'm getting the `Argument must be a range.` error with this `=Arrayformula(row(A5:"A"&INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B),1)))` using this answer to get the last non'empty cell in columnn `B` https://stackoverflow.com/a/43141556/10789707

Comment: Found the sequence method `=SEQUENCE(INDEX(B5:B,COUNTA(B5:B),1)+1, 1, MIN(B5,INDEX(B5:B,COUNTA(B5:B),1)+1), 1)` but still curious of a way with a string if possible.