# Lookup last value in sheet where other cell contains value

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to find the last instance of a value in a sheet. The value is an amount of currency, and the condition should be if the type of currency is Income. For example, I have a sheet with

```
Date        Name          Amount  Type
2019-08-01  Cash on hand  52.52   Income - Allowance
2019-08-02  Cash on hand  33.33   Income - Hourly
```

and I want to match the latest amount of income (`33.33`) and display it in another cell.

I've tried something like `=INDEX(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)));ROWS(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))))` from [Get the last non-empty cell in a column in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8161172/1781430) where instead of `NOT(ISBLANK())` I tried to put `"Income*`.  I also tried to do a chain of `MAX(FILTER())`, but I got an error:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 999. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A2:D, "select C where D matches 'Incom.*' offset "&COUNTA(
 QUERY(A2:D, "select C where D matches 'Incom.*'", 0))-1, 0)
```

[image: 0]