# How do you find the last used row in column A of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I modify the below to give me the last row of column A. At the moment it calculates the last row of all the columns.

```
function Test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  Browser.msgBox(lastRow);
}
```

I saw the below in another post and tried replacing mySheet with ss but that didn't give me the correct output.

```
var lastCell = mySheet.getRange(mySheet.getLastRow(),1).getNextDataCell(
  SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last non-empty cell in a column in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116043/get-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
function Test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var colAValues = ss.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(function(el){
    return el != "";
  });

  var lr = colAValues.length;
  Browser.msgBox(lr); // replaced "lastRow" with "lr"
}
```

Hope this helps but do please let know in case it doesn't :)

Comment: Awesome, appreciate the help.