# Using LOOKUP (2,1/ function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Using function

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((B8>=A1:A5)*(B8<=B1:B5)),C1:C5)
```

to lookup a value between two numbers doesn't seem to work in Google Sheets while in Excel it does. Does anyone know the alternative to this function in Google Sheets, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting the last value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169914/selecting-the-last-value-of-a-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/((B8>=A1:A5)*(B8<=B1:B5)),C1:C5))
```