# Why doesn't ArrayFormula work with LOOKUP function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to extract value (Delivery Zone Code) from column C, based on a lookup value (Zip/Postcode) in F2. The lookup value falls between min and max ranges.

[image]

Here is a sample sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JOMxM9gerT5zLVW0ZJtgjiF04Sw5bAXAPqtGXmst6cQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have found a formula which works in excel:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((F2>=A2:A351)/(F2<=B2:B351)),C2:C351)
```

But it doesn't work in Google Sheets. I have added arrayformula based on another answer - [Using LOOKUP (2,1/ function in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571041/using-lookup-2-1-function-in-google-sheets#new-answer)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/((F2>=A2:A351)/(F2<=B2:B351)),C2:C351))
```

But this formula still returns #N/A...

In the examples, zip code 3185 should return the value MEL

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this formula instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(F2, 
 {INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A:A))*1, 
  INDIRECT("D2:D"&COUNTA(A:A))}, 2))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That works on the demo sheet but on another sheet I am trying to reference all individual postcodes into their respective zones but getting NA for values in the middle of lookup ranges:

http://prntscr.com/oep5oy

http://prntscr.com/oep5tv

Any suggestions?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L8rjiN5KtlIQeByijwMoRZ_iTOhv340jCeaj6NqrWPM/edit?usp=sharing