# Finding adjacent column values from the last non-null row of a certain column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Is there a simple in-built function to select adjacent values from the last non-null row for a certain column?

In the below example the last non-null value in **Column A** is "E", and I'd like to select the corresponding value "13" from the next column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`=VLOOKUP(INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))),A1:B,2,0)`

Refer [Selecting the last value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4169914/1330560). There are 22 answers toi choose from.

I like `=INDEX(I:I;MAX((I:I<>"")*(ROW(I:I))))`. It is one of the shortest **and** it copes with blank rows.

Add `VLOOKUP` and you can get the value on the adjacent columns.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` could return the wrong value if there aren't unique values in column A.

A slight tweak to your preferred solution will solve this: `=INDEX(A:B;MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))),2)`

Comment: One works with the data available, but this is a point nicely made.

Answer (score 1):

```
=indirect("B" & max(ARRAYFORMULA(row(A1:A)*if(A1:A="",0,1))),true)
```

or

```
=indirect("B" & arrayformula(max(if(A1:A<>"",row(A1:A),0))),true)
```

or with offset

```
=offset(B1,ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(if(A:A="",0,row(A:A))))-1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(A3:B, "select B where A !='' offset "&COUNTA(A3:A)-1)
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A"&MAX(IF(A2:A="",,ROW(A2:A)))), A2:B, 2, 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(QUERY({A2:A, ROW(A2:A)}, 
 "where Col1 !='' order by Col2 desc"), 1, 1), A2:B, 2, 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The first query does it for me-simplicity. Would you mind, for those less talented (such as myself), explaining the significance/role of `row(A2:A)` in the last example?

Comment: sure, ROW(A2:A) in combination with ArrayFormula will create array of numbers per each row that was found so in this case it would be array of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,etc,etc... and as per virtual array {} its on the 2nd position which is picked up as Col2 by QUERY. simply put its just a simple reverse of rows